# I want to Capture a alphanumeric group without underscore

Tags: java, regex

I want to Capture an alphanumeric group in regex such that it does not capture starting underscore. For example `_reverse(abc)` should return `reverse(`. I am using `(?<name>\w+)` but it `return _reverse(`.

Comment: do you need other special characters (more then _ or '()')?

Comment: \w group contains a-zA-Zand underscore... so maybe try explicitly mentioning [a-zA-Z]+

Comment: Why not accepting any answer yet? Is your issue solved? You can refer to [the Tour page](https://www.stackoverflow.com/tour) for more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this,

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9()\\s+]
```

The output will be `reverse(abc)`

Comment: For this case this may give output but there may be nested structure as well. For example reverse(reverse(_reverse(abc),1,2))_reverse(abc)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify characters explicitly, e.g.:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you are showing, I assume you want to strip underscores and content behind the opening parentheses.

Basically, that *should*  work with a regex like this:

```
"_([a-zA-Z0-9]+\()"
```

this can be used in conjunction with a `Matcher` to extract all capturing groups (in this case, `[a-zA-Z0-9]+\(`) and return them.

Note that you can find almost all the help you need with Regular Expressions on utility sites like [RegEx 101](https://regex101.com/) and [RegEx Per](https://regexper.com/), the latter being a nice visualizer but only working with `javaScript`-like expressions.
Also, RegEx 101 contains a Regex Debugger to help avoid [dangerous regular expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)

Comment: _ may or may not be there.

Comment: that can be remedied witn a `?` qualifier, however that will make this regex be *very* generous. If the *only* text is `_something(...)` then that will suffice, however if there is more than one occurrence of this, it *may* cause problems - as such, adding `\\s` before `_?` would be necessary., meaning `"\\s_?([a-zA-Z0-9]+\\()"`